# Ajax load a page like an include 

Tags: ajax, include

I have a problem: I need to load a set of includes with ajax, but when I make the ajax
and request the current URL, I get the page url.

I have a problem when I call a page via ajax; the problem is when I try to get the request
URL in the page which is called with ajax, because it doesn't work like an include.

**For example**: I have my page "prueba.adp" and "prueba-ajax.adp"

The page prueba.adp calls via ajax to prueba-ajax.adp.

So when I try to get the request URL in prueba-ajax.adp I get prueba-ajax.adp, but
if I set an include I get prueba.adp.

Do you know any way to execute the ajax page and get the request url of the page which made the ajax call?

Comment: Hello, note that this site is in English. Could you try and translate your question?

Comment: almost.. but it's not http://stackoverflow.es

Comment: So...who will translate the answers?

Comment: What do you mean by an "include"? Do you mean an ADP include? How are you "requesting the current URL"?

Comment: I mean if i can execute code in the ajax way keeping the same context. 

That your code excecuted in the ajax when you request the actual url in the ajax code , will be the same if you request the url in the page who request the ajax,

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding you. If you give a code example of the problem, I can help.